# Agora Chat integration in React native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am new in react native and I want to achieve text chat functionality with agora in react native.

Currently, I'm encountering an issue where if a user is not on the chat screen and receives messages from another user, those unread messages are appended at the end after the older messages load. Additionally, when the user sends a new message, it gets added along with the same old unread messages.

Please suggest what I did wrong, also if my explanation needs some data, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Below is my code implementation:

```
import { Image, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useContext, useRef } from 'react'
import { GiftedChat, Send, Bubble } from 'react-native-gifted-chat'
import { IconButton } from 'react-native-paper'
import { ChatMessage, ChatMessageChatType } from 'react-native-agora-chat'
import MCIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { AuthContext } from '../../../context/AuthContext'

function CustomInputToolbar(props) {
  const { text, setText, sendmsg } = props

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        // flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        gap: 10,
        marginHorizontal: 8,
      }}
    >
      <TextInput
        style={[styles.input, { paddingTop: 10 }]}
        placeholder="Message"
        placeholderTextColor="gray"
        value={text}
        onChangeText={setText}
        multiline
      />
      <MCIcon
        name="send"
        color="#dd1077"
        size={32}
        onPress={() => {
          if (text !== '') {
            sendmsg()
            setText('')
          }
        }}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

function ChatScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { tokenData, profileData, chatClient, chatManager } = route.params
  const logoutCalled = useRef(false)
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('')
  const { chatNotification } = useContext(AuthContext)

  // console.log(JSON.stringify(tokenData))

  const { markChatRead } = useContext(AuthContext)

  // Custom bubble component to change background color to pink
  const renderBubble = (props) => (
    <Bubble
      {...props}
      wrapperStyle={{
        right: {
          backgroundColor: '#dd1077',
        },
        left: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        },
      }}
    />
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    markChatRead(tokenData.conversationId)

    const login = async () => {
      console.log('start login ...')
      try {
        await chatClient.isLoginBefore()
        await chatClient.loginWithAgoraToken(tokenData?.username, tokenData?.token)
        console.log('login operation success.')
        loadOldMessages()
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`login fail: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
      }
    }

    const loadOldMessages = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await chatManager.fetchHistoryMessagesByOptions(tokenData.toUsername, 0, {
          cursor: '',
          pageSize: 50,
        })

        const newMessages = res.list.map((message) => ({
          _id: message.msgId,
          text: message.body.content,
          createdAt: new Date(message.serverTime),
          user: {
            _id: message.from,
            name: message.from,
            avatar: '',
          },
          received: true,
        }))

        setMessages((previousMessages) => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, newMessages))
        setMessageListener() // Call setMessageListener after setting the messages
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching old messages:', error)
      }
    }

    const setMessageListener = () => {
      const msgListener = {
        onMessagesReceived(receivedMessages) {
          const newMessages = receivedMessages
            .filter((message) => message.from === tokenData.toUsername)
            .map((message) => ({
              _id: message.msgId,
              text: message.body.content,
              createdAt: new Date(message.serverTime),
              user: {
                _id: message.from,
                name: message.from,
                avatar: '',
              },
              received: false,
            }))
          setMessages((previousMessages) => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, newMessages))
        },
        onCmdMessagesReceived: (messages) => {},
        onMessagesRead: (messages) => {},
        onGroupMessageRead: (groupMessageAcks) => {},
        onMessagesDelivered: (messages) => {},
        onMessagesRecalled: (messages) => {},
        onConversationsUpdate: () => {},
        onConversationRead: (from, to) => {},
      }
      chatManager.removeAllMessageListener()
      chatManager.addMessageListener(msgListener)
    }

    login()
  }, [])

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(
      () => () => {
        if (!logoutCalled.current) {
          logoutCalled.current = true
          logout()
          if (navigation && navigation.getState().routes.slice(-1)[0].name !== 'ChatList') {
            navigation.goBack()
          }
          // navigation.goBack()
        }
      },
      [navigation]
    )
  )

  const onSend = useCallback((messages = []) => {
    setMessages((previousMessages) => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages))
  }, [])

  const logout = () => {
    console.log('start logout ...')
    chatClient
      .logout()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('logout success.')
      })
      .catch((reason) => {
        console.log(`logout fail:${JSON.stringify(reason)}`)
      })
  }

  // Sends a text message to somebody.
  const sendmsg = () => {
    let msg = ChatMessage.createTextMessage(
      tokenData.toUsername,
      text,
      ChatMessageChatType.PeerChat
    )
    const callback = new (class {
      onProgress(locaMsgId, progress) {
        console.log(`send message process: ${locaMsgId}, ${progress}`)
      }

      onError(locaMsgId, error) {
        console.log(`send message fail: ${locaMsgId}, ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
      }

      onSuccess(message) {
        console.log(`send message success: ${message.localMsgId}`)
        const newMessage = {
          _id: message.msgId,
          text: message.body.content,
          createdAt: new Date(message.serverTime),
          user: {
            _id: message.from,
            name: message.from,
            avatar: '',
          },
          sent: true,
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(newMessage))
        chatNotification(tokenData.conversationId, message.body.content)
        setMessages((previousMessages) => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, newMessage))
      }
    })()
    console.log('start send message ...')
    chatClient.chatManager
      .sendMessage(msg, callback)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`send message: ${msg.localMsgId} ${JSON.stringify(msg)}`)
      })
      .catch((reason) => {
        console.log(`send fail: ${JSON.stringify(reason)}`)
      })
  }

  function CustomSendButton(props) {
    return (
      <Send {...props}>
        <View style={{ marginRight: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../../../assets/icons/bookmark-white.png')}
            resizeMode={'cover'}
          />
        </View>
      </Send>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          paddingLeft: 16,
        }}
      >
        {/* Arrow icon */}
        <IconButton
          icon={() => <MCIcon name="chevron-left" color="#fff" size={30} />}
          onPress={() => {
            logoutCalled.current = true
            logout()
            navigation.goBack()
          }}
        />
        {/* Profile image */}
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: profileData.profileImageUrl || profileData.profileImage,
          }}
          style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 40 }}
        />
        <View
          style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-start', marginLeft: 10, width: 200 }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'white' }}>
            {(profileData.role
              ? profileData.role.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + profileData.role.slice(1)
              : '') ||
              (profileData.type
                ? profileData.type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + profileData.type.slice(1)
                : '')}
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
            {profileData.firstName} {profileData.lastName}{' '}
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{profileData.title}</Text>
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, color: 'white' }}>
            {profileData.university || profileData.institution}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <GiftedChat
        messages={messages}
        onSend={(messages) => onSend(messages)}
        alwaysShowSend
        renderAvatar={null}
        renderSend={(props) => <CustomSendButton {...props} />}
        renderInputToolbar={(props) => (
          <CustomInputToolbar {...props} text={text} setText={setText} sendmsg={sendmsg} />
        )}
        renderBubble={renderBubble}
        bottomOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 100 : 0}
        // messagesContainerStyle={{  }}
        user={{
          _id: tokenData.username,
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default ChatScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    color: 'black',
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
})
```